# Limit and offset in Active Record joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, limit, offset

I'd like to apply a limit and offset to the following Active Record query:

```
results = ForumThread.joins(:posts).where(:posts => {:some_integer => 123})
```

Note ForumThread :has_many posts association in the model.

I tried including an `@options` hash in the where clause. I tried appending `.limit(5)` to the end of the query. However neither of these work. Reading [Active Record Query Interface guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) didn't help either. **How can I apply limit and offset to my query?**

I'm open to modifying the query if an alternative finder method is more appropriate.

Comment: What query is being generated and executed as shown in `log/development.log`?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "forums_threads" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."forum_thread_id" = "forum_threads"."id" WHERE "posts"."some_integer" = '123'`. This is without adding a limit anywhere.

Comment: What query do you get with the `limit(5)` condition appended? Also what RDBMS are you using in the back end?

Comment: same query with `LIMIT 5` appended to the end. I'm puzzled by the fact that `results.count` is much larger than the value passed to limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query contains `COUNT(*)` since I was calling `results.count` later. Apparently `SELECT COUNT(*)` ignores limit clauses hence appending `LIMIT(5)` to the query had no effect.

Comment: @tadman indeed. However there's a time-delay since I answered my own question.